# Why do gravitational waves or electromagnetic waves exist?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, radiation, gravitational-waves

Maxwell equations or Einstein field equations imply the existence of electromagnetic waves and gravitational waves. How can these waves persist on (vacuum) space if they radiate (and loose) energy?

Answer (score 7):

It's not the waves that radiate energy but the sources of the waves. The waves *are* the radiated energy. They carry energy away from a source. The energy moves from place to place, and becomes more and more thinly spread as it moves away from the source.